# Use jaxb2Marshaller for Datanucleus Entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, datanucleus, jaxb2

I'm building application using Spring 3 MVC framework and Google App Engine Datanucleus JPA,
my Entity Class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Incident {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
  private String incidentId;

  @Persistent
  @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.pk-id", value = "true")
  private Long keyId;

  private List<String> requests;

  @XmlElement(name="sr")
  public List<String> getRequests() {
    return requests;
  }

  public void setRequests(List<String> requests) {
    this.requests = requests;
  }

  [...]
}
```

I'm trying to send it to other application using `jaxb2Marshalleg r -` but when I have `@XmlElement(name="sr")` annotation in it I'm getting:

```
2012-08-07 10:02:17 org.datanucleus.metadata.AbstractClassMetaData determineObjectIdClass 
SEVERE: Class pl.km.smartcity.datastore.Incident has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. 
Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.
Class pl.km.smartcity.datastore.Incident has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.
```

When I remove this annotation, it works, but of course my request list is not passed when I'm passing object.

Comment: Using which version of GAE JPA ? and what is that @Persistent supposed to be on "keyId" ? That is a JDO annotation.

Comment: I'm using GAE 1.7 with datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5. I've already removed this @Persistent annotation - my mistake (I'm new in Datanucleus) error is still the same

Comment: So use v2.x of GAE JPA. The one you have (1.0) is prehistoric